# Rails 3 'test the truth' unit test failing after migrations mess-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rails-activerecord

Finished tests in 0.074964s, 13.3398 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

```
  1) Error:
test_the_truth(UserTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `tickets` (`status`, `assignee`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`, `project_id`, `user_id`) VALUES ('MyString', 1, '2013-02-22 12:40:19', '2013-02-22 12:40:19', 980190962, 64810937, 64810937)
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
```

I generated/scaffolded models and everything. 
The peculiar part is that I don't remember having a user_id column in the table.
Furthermore, schema.db and all migrations do not have anything like this as well.
I do not have such string (user_id) in my **workspace**
How does rails my column should be named like that?

Apparently there had been such thing as a column in the database but it got fixed in some weird messy way.

P.S. If I disable the fixtures related to this table, it's all good.

What is going on, from where does rails read this column name from, cause apparently it is not from my workspace and neither my db or the test db.So it probably stores it somewhere? Is there a way can I fix this mess?

Comment: Is it there in your Ticket fixture? if it is remove the field and try to run tests again.

Answer (score 1):

A minute after it I ask in SO, I find the answer myself, after hours gone to nothing before. This always happens to me.

The answer is exactly what Rubyman commented - the fixtures should be modified to remove any legacy information! But it was a bit more subtle - I really did not have 'user_id' column/string anywhere in my fixtures, as I did not have it in my workspace. BUT, as I am using 'belongs_to' and 'has_many', it would not be named 'user_id' in the model and anywhere,  it would be named just 'user'. So I searched and found a 'user' field in the fixture and had to remove it in order to fix the erroneus 'user_id' column name generated in the SQL.

Hope this helps somebody.